# C# - No colon symbol (":") allowed in XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, mono

I'm using C# and Mono to write a library which can generate dictionaries for Apple macOS official dictionary app. The dictionary source code is a XML document, and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    This is a sample dictionary source file.
    It can be built using Dictionary Development Kit.
-->
<d:dictionary xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng">
<d:entry id="dictionary_application" d:title="Dictionary application">
    <d:index d:value="Dictionary application"/>
    <h1>Dictionary application </h1>
    <p>
        An application to look up dictionary on Mac OS X.<br/>
    </p>
</d:entry></d:dictionary>
```

And the problem is, the element's local name contains a colon symbol, and I run my code, it throws me an exception when it goes to **WriteStartElement** method and tells me this:

> Invalid name character in 'd:dictionary'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

So I would like to ask that, how should I solve this problem and write the local name with the colon symbol in it?

Comment: 'd:' identifies the namespace. Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using xml linq which is an enhanced Net Library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string header = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<d:dictionary xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:d=\"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng\">" +
                "</d:dictionary>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement dictionary = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace dNs = dictionary.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("d");
            XNamespace defaultNs = dictionary.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XElement newDict = new XElement(dNs + "entry", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("id", "dictionary_application"),
                new XAttribute("title","Dictionary application"),
                new XElement(dNs + "index", new XAttribute("value", "Dictionary application")),
                new XElement(defaultNs + "h1", "Dictionary application"),
                new XElement(defaultNs + "p", "An application to look up in dictionary on Mac OS X.")
            });

            dictionary.Add(newDict);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tested your program's output is incorrect. The line:<d:index d:value="Dictionary application"/>

Comment: But yours is: **<d:index value="Dictionary application"/>**

Comment: Okay now I've tried, change the code `new XElement(dNs + "index", new XAttribute("value", "Dictionary application")),` to `new XElement(dNs + "index", new XAttribute(dNs + "value", "Dictionary application")),`

Answer (score 2):

Notice that element local name is the part after colon, for example the `dictionary` in `d:dictionary`. The part before colon is the namespace prefix. That said, you don't want to write element local name with colon. You want to write element with namespace prefix instead, which can be done using overload of `WriteStartElement()` that accept three string parameters :

```
string prefix = "d";
string localName = "dictionary";
string namespaceUri = "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng";
writer.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, namespaceUri);
```

Reference : [MSDN - `XmlWriter.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, namespace)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cdfkth5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)